# How handle visibility change of property in class when using serialized objects?

Tags: php, object, serialization, visibility

UPDATE:
As someone says this question is a bit unclear. I couldn't really understand it myself. But I did dig up the solution. [It's a PHP bug that has been resolved](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49649). The server this legacy code runs on has an outdated php version.

Old code:

```
class MyChildClass extends MyBaseClass
{
    protected $myProp = "foo";
}

class MyBaseClass {
}

$myObject = new MyChildClass();

$myObjectS = serialize($myObject);
```

New code:

```
class MyChildClass extends MyBaseClass
{
}

class MyBaseClass {
    public $myProp;
}
// $myObjectS is the same as in the Old code above.
$myObject = unserialize($myObjectS);
```

This will result in an object with a protected property $myProp with a value of "foo". But there will also be a public property with the same name with an undefined value.

I really do not know how to fix this. The result I want is to have the objects public property populated with the serialized objects value for its protected property.

I would not design the code like this with the serialization of complete objects. But this is a legacy project where I (for the time being) have to deal with this.

Comment: Your question is not clear ..

Comment: I also cannot make sense of your question. I have to assume "Old code" and "New code" are two separate PHP files, since they define the same classes, but then where is `$myObjectS` in "New code" coming from? It must be from "Old code", but that's another file. Or not? What? Why call it "Old" and "New" in the first place, that must have a meaning... normally you would say that when you replace code, but I don't think that's the case here... or is it?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The "old code" is to show how the object got serialized. That same object, in its serialized state is present in "new code"

Answer (score 0):

Not easy as you'll have to change all the occurencies of protected properties in `$myObjects`.

In your example `{s:7:"*myProp";s:3:"foo";}` become `{s:6:"myProp";s:3:"foo";}`.
Set length of `myProp` from `7` to `6`, and remove the leading star of `*myProp`. Lot of work if you have lot of protected properties :/